# How to remove all but certain characters from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace, char

Assume you had a string "`ACcwerwervwvrwBq^2424 /.* DffGZ..'B`". How would you only keep certain characters like `A,B,C,D` and remove the rest?

`string.replaceAll` seems to work if I know what characters to remove, but I want to remove all characters except `A,B,C,D`. Putting every character in there except those 4 seems pretty tedious, what the easier way?

I want the output in the above case to be "`ACBDB`".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use regex something like:

```
str.replaceAll("[^ABCD]", "");
```

Should do it

Answer (score 3):

You just need a proper regex:

`s.replaceAll("[^ABCD]", "")`